# Joomla 2.5.9 Domain name repeating in URL

Tags: php, joomla, iis-7, joomla2.5

I have installed the Joomla 2.5.9 on Windows server with IIS7 . :) 
I disabled all the SEF setting in configuration.

Now , I logged in to admin of joomla 2.5.9. When I see the public side , it show it perfect.. but when I go for any other link.. it have multiple time of domain name in url..

like...

```
http://domainname.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=6&Itemid=102
```

I tried with enabling SEO URL , and enabled the web.conf. and settings like below,

Search Engine Friendly URLs -yes
Use URL rewriting -yes
Adds Suffix to URL -yes.

```
http://domainname.com/domainname.com/features.html
```

is this error with joomla 2.5.9???

Thanks,
Gaurish

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=615&t=820080

Answer (score 0):

Change in `configuration.php`

```
var $live_site = '';
```

to

```
var $live_site = 'http://domainname.com';
```

Comment: Have you tried to use www.domainname.com instead of domainname.com?

Comment: I think it might be something to do with the htaccess file rather than the config.php

Comment: @Lodder Its reasonable assumption, but after I did some research, many people with same problem used this solution.

Comment: @Gaurish Well perhaps you should try to upload [this](http://docs.joomla.org/Htaccess_examples_%28security%29) Joomla 2.5 htacces and give it try

Comment: hey.. guys thanks for your reply.. but I can't use htaccess as this is hosted on Godaddy's **IIS7 - windows** server ..

Comment: one more thing I found, my php script under FastCGi.. is this one of reason.. ???

Answer (score 0):

I tested with some configuration & that works for me..
I tried [JTC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1757877/jtc) code,

```
public $live_site = 'http://domainname.com';
```

It works on front-end, but throws the error in backend , even I am not able to Login in admin.

So, I changed the configuration file as below,

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (true== strpos(strtolower($url),'administrator')) :

class JConfig {
.......
public $live_site = '';
......
}
else:
class JConfig {
......
public $live_site = 'http://www.domainname.com/';
.....
}
endif;
```

and this work perfectly for me.. all the URL's on front-end are showing correct, not domain name repeated.

But URL's in back are showing same as early, but I can do the updates & admin task there.. that really don't interrupt me.

One more think , I am not able update global configuration file.. as we edited it .. so I need do it manually.

Thanks,
Gaurish